# If Statement with 2 Variables - Bash

Tags: bash, scripting

I am trying to write a single IF statement which can check two variables at once.

I have two variables, for example:
$VARA
$VARB

Both with either contain a 0 or a non 0 value.  I need an if statement which can check both and if either are not equal to 0, if will perform an action, if both are 0 if will perform a different action.

With a single variable, I can do this:

```
if [ $VARA -ne 0 ]
then echo 'The operation failed! VARA is not equal to 0'
else echo 'The operation suceeded! VARA is equal to 0'
fi
```

However, I am not sure how to check both VARA and VARB at the same time.  Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

```
if [ "$VARA" -eq 0 ] && [ "$VARB" -eq 0 ]
then echo 'both are zero, do something'
else echo 'do something else'
fi
```

Comment: Could even use the -a syntax `if [ $VARA -eq 0 -a $VARB -eq 0 ]; then...`.  -a is and and -o is or.

Comment: Likewise, the `&&` can be replaced with `||` in circumstances where you need to use a logical *or* instead of *and*. While `-a` and `-o` can also be used to avoid the usage of multiple `[]` pairs, some people prefer the method Lucas cited for the sake of readability.

Comment: This will break if `$VARA` or `$VARB` are more than two words long under wordsplitting. They should be quoted appropriately.

Comment: @ChrisDown what do you mean? like putting the vars  between '    ' ?

Comment: @LucasKauffman: Like putting the vars between `"` double quotes.  Single quotes will not work, as they will prevent variable expansion.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (( var_a == 0 && var_b == 0 )); then
   # ...
fi
```

In Bash, always use (( ... )) for arithmetic evaluations.